# How to get files downloaded by yum?

Tags: linux, fedora, yum, software-installation

I install a software package on Fedora from the terminal using the command like

> `# yum install live-usb-creator`

Now at first it downloads some of the packages from online repository and then later it install that files on to the system.

Now I want a backup of that downloaded files so that in future I can install that packages directly without connecting to internet.

But the problem is that I don't know where does it download that all files.

If it is possible to get those files then I have two systems having `Fedora 13 i686` installed on both of them. One has Internet connection and other has nothing like that.

Now I want to install sofwares using `yum` on the first system from the online repository and after that can I install the same sofwares on my second system from the downloaded files on the first system?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set

```
keepcache=1
```

in yum.conf

Then future rpms should stay under /var/cache/yum

Comment: Thanks @jamespo , It works well. But what about installing those files on another system?

Comment: If you want to share rpms, another way to do it might be to use a local proxy (like squid) and set it to cache rpm's aggressively. Then set yum up on your multiple machines to use that proxy.

Comment: Okay Thanks **@jamespo**, now can I use that local proxy on that same machine? Please post some usefull links where I can get the whole idea. I have no option for installing software on that machine.

Answer (score 3):

I googled and found [this](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/yum-downloadonly-plugin/). You can install the `downloadonly` plugin using `yum install yum-downloadonly`. Then you can use the flag `--downloadonly` for the concerned package. This, probably, isn't the exact solution to your question. But I think it would be useful.

Also checkout Q.14 on [this](http://yum.baseurl.org/wiki/Faq). It might help as well.